# Making a route between a Java (Spring) back end and an AngularJS front end

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to Spring and AngularJS and I'm trying to make a route from my back end to my front end controller.
My Spring back end:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("test1")
public class TestController {
    public TestController() {}

    @RequestMapping(value="test2", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional("defaultTransactionManager")
    public String getSearch() {
        System.out.println("It reaches here!");
        return ("Test Success!");
    }
}
```

My AngularJS front end:

```
this.testingHTTP = (vm) => {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url:SERVICE_URL + '/test1/test2',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },

      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        vm.testerDiv = response;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response, 'Test failed');
      });
    };
```

When I run the front end function, "It reaches here!" appears in my backend console, and this appears in my browser console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
>       at handleResponseError (defaultServices.js:48)
>       at processQueue (angular.js:17330)
>       at angular.js:17378
>       at Scope.$digest (angular.js:18515)
>       at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18903)
>       at done (angular.js:12775)
>       at completeRequest (angular.js:13032)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12937) "Test failed"

I know the url is correct; is it something about my Content-Type perhaps? What am I missing?

Comment: Add `console.log(response);` after function successCallback, then see really got result on the console. Maybe `this.testerDiv = response;` cause an error

Comment: And some suggestions for you: 1-) use angular 2 or over versions 2-) Use nice word for clean code (what is test1, test2 for request mapping) 3-)Learn annotation and use when you just need(@ResponseBody
    @Transactional("defaultTransactionManager") for testing you do not need)

Comment: its failing. in the browser console output, you can see that it says “Test Failed”. However, I switch the content type to ‘text/plain’ the success callback is activated but the response is undefined, not “Test Success!” like it should be.

Comment: 1) cant use angular; company uses angularjs 2) test1 and test2 are made up routes for stackoverflow 3) Im not familiar with Spring and am replicating code from another part of the project. I didn’t realize it wasn’t relevant for debugging

Comment: Try wrapping your return inside of a DTO class, if you want to return a json. That string can not be converted to a valid json. Since there is no valid json returned, angular can not parse it into the `response` object.

Comment: so  angular `Response` object should be `JSON`, change  Spring `Controller` response to `return "{"data":"Test"}".`

Comment: Thank you! I changed the back end to return a HashMap of {"status": "success"} instead of a String and I changed the front end to vm.testerDiv = response["data"]["status"]; If you want to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I don't think "{'data':'Test'}" works unless you change the Content-Type to text/plain (at least according to my test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular JS expects the response to be `JSON` by default. So you need to return the response as JSON String from `Spring Controller` like below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("test1")
public class TestController {
    public TestController() {}

    @RequestMapping(value="test2", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @Transactional("defaultTransactionManager")
    public String getSearch() {
        System.out.println("It reaches here!");
        return  "{\"resp\":\"Test Success\"}";
    }
}
```

And in your success resposne in angularjs you should do `response.resp` to get `Test Success` value.